# Can negative toughness effects kill a creature?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

There are some spells and abilities that subtract from a creature's power/toughness: for example, part of [Ulcerate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUlcerate%5d) says "Target creature gets -3/-3 until end of turn."

If the target creature is only a 2/2, is that target destroyed (goes to graveyard) from the -3 toughness given to it? If not what happens, does it stick around with negative toughness?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A creature with 0 or less toughness will be sent to the graveyard immediately, so yes, getting -3/-3 can kill a creature.

Note that this is not technically being "destroyed", it is a different way of sending the creature to the graveyard. This matters for things like regeneration.

From the [basic MTG rules](http://www.wizards.com/magic/rules/EN_Magic_Basic_Rulebook_20090710.pdf):

> Your creatures go to your graveyard if the damage they’re dealt 
>   in a single turn is equal to or greater than their toughness, 
>   or if their toughness is reduced to 0 or less.

Comment: Just in case anyone is looking for the comprehensive rules, rule **704.5f** describes the action that moves a creature to the graveyard, and rule **121.1a** explains how counters affect toughness. I didn't post this as an answer because the basic rules are definitely more suitable here.

Comment: It's moved to the graveyard the next time SBA are checked, which for most purposes is effectively "immediately", but there are cases where it's not.